Does kubernetes keep crashed container logs?
When a container which runs as part of a Kubernetes pod crashes, does running kubectl logs <pod-name> will give me the logs of the crashed container?
From an experiment I did - it doesn't, but I wonder if that's something that is well defined as part of kubernetes way of operation or just something arbitrary in my specific case?

It probably has more to do with your kubernetes provider than anything else and what their log retention policies are.  Add that to the question so the right people can jump in.

In short - no. see docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#log-rotation.

If you want to see logs of the crashed container, As I experienced you can use Lens and open the crashed container's logs page at this moment, Lens will keep all logs until you close it. Lens webiste -> https://k8slens.dev/

No, you will not be able to get a crashed containers logs after the pod has exited and left. You need to handle the logging yourself. You could mount a network file share (such as EFS on AWS) on to the pod and have the logs written directly into it, which would mean the logs are persisted on the file share. Or you could use the ELK stack to push logs to elasticsearch. Or you could have your application directly write its logs into a persistent volume hosted somewhere. But ultimately this is not something Kubernetes provides.
